# C# 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SslStream'.'

Tags: c#

The exception in my questions title is being thrown on the line return allMessages; in the code below.  I don't understand it because that line of code is still within the using (var sslStream...) statement, so by the time it is executed the SslStream object should not be disposed..

```
public static List<Message> FetchAllMessages(string hostname, int port, string username, string password, string proxyIp, int proxyPort)
{
    // The client disconnects from the server when being disposed
    using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
    {
        var proxyClient = new HttpProxyClient(proxyIp, proxyPort);
        using (var sslStream = new SslStream(proxyClient.CreateConnection(hostname, port).GetStream()))
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
            client.Connect(sslStream);
            // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
            client.Authenticate(username, password);
            // Get the number of messages in the inbox
            int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

            // We want to download all messages
            List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);

            // Messages are numbered in the interval: [1, messageCount]
            // Ergo: message numbers are 1-based.
            // Most servers give the latest message the highest number
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
            }
                            // Now return the fetched messages
            return allMessages;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATES:

Put a breakpoint on return allMessages; and hovered over the sslStream object, it is not disposed.

When I remove the using statement and just declare var sslStream it works but I don't think this would scale well without it..

Comment: There must be something about `client.GetMessage(i)`. Try to clone it. Well, right. client holds to the message, you add message to list. This is same instance. When you dispose client, it disposes message. Try doing `ToMailMessage` and add to list. This should work

Comment: Check the updated comment. When I say "clone it", I mean, you need to try adding to list not the same message held by client

Comment: @T.S. This code worked earlier, which is really why I was confused.  So I did the catch all troubleshooting of restarting my computer and it just ran successfully.  I literally have no idea why that fixed the problem.

Comment: Try this. Call `bytes = client.GetMessageAsBytes();` then `list.Add(new Message(bytes));`. Should do it. This is your clone mechanism. If this works, I'll post pretty solution answer. Let me know

Comment: Thanks @T.S. I threw some rep your way for trying, but the solution was literally to just restart my computer(!?).  Appreciate the help though.  If I run into this again I will implement your advice.

Comment: Well, if you have this issue once, you will have it again. Its something with finalizers or something like that. Lifecycle of your object, you know... Could be even a bug in pop3 objects.

Comment: @T.S. The pop3 objects are from a pretty widely used/updated open source library on github so they should be good.  I feel like something was wrong with Visual Studio, I just installed a pending update after restarting.  This code has worked after quite a few tests then just suddenly ran into this problem out of nowhere seemingly...quite odd but atleast it's working now.

Comment: We recently started using MySql DB among others. And we plugged-in as you said, *"pretty widely used/updated open source library"* , which is MySQL Data Provider for .net. into sqlServ/Oracle system that worked for 15 years. MySql had a show-stopper bug in it, which I eliminated buy building proxies around it. Then I reported 3 visual studio bugs this year as well. 2 were fixed already. So, you know, bugs are there

Comment: @T.S. Oh yeah, I'm just saying it's been peer reviewed/adopted to a decent degree.  It is just hard to tell exactly what was causing the problem, I agree a bug in the library is possible.  I was really surprised when the restart fixed it because I figured that was a long shot.  Could just be a band aid, if so, I will come back to these comments and refactor as you suggested.

Comment: I would use **dotPeek** to reflect `SslStream` and `po3Client` and look into its `Dispose`

Answer (score 3):

So, I don't really have an explanation as to why, but restarting my computer solved the problem, the code runs fine after doing that...

Comment: Seriously? That is unexpected!